# Refresh Notes Free Time/ Calendar Entries Programmatically

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

We are using a small javascript library for creating new calendar entries in personal notes calendar via XPages. All the application users have an option to select from the available free times. However, recently we noticed that the free time actually also shows up the time at which actually a meeting is scheduled. At this time if we manually refresh the calendar then all the free time are displayed correctly, however, we would like to find a solution to refresh it programmatically.

I have tried to lookup online with no success so any help would be really appreciated.

Edit 1 - Detailed Description

We use the script library provided by Ulrich Krause [here](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-calendar-entry-with-ssjs) for creating new calendar entries. Further, in the frontend, we have a repeat control to display all the free time. Just providing a small snippet for the idea:

```
// This codes shows all the free time for the field named "members" in the main document

try{
var infoDoc:NotesDocument= database.getDocumentByUNID(context.getUrlParameter('refId'));
var meetingDuration = infoDoc.getItemValueInteger("meetingDuration");
var start:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(getComponent("startF").getValue());
var end:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(getComponent("endF").getValue());
var window:NotesDateRange = session.createDateRange();
window.setStartDateTime(start);
window.setEndDateTime(end);
// Set up the names
var names = new java.util.Vector();
var infoDoc:NotesDocument= database.getDocumentByUNID(context.getUrlParameter('refId'));
names = infoDoc.getItemValue("members");
// Find the free time
var freetime:java.util.Vector = session.freeTimeSearch(window,meetingDuration, names, false);
return freetime;
}catch(err){
view.postScript("alert('"+err+"')")
}
```

The problem we are facing is that even after creating a calendar entry (via the script library mentioned), it still shows up in the free time until it is manually refreshed from NOTES. We are intending to do that programmatically with no success.

Edit 2: Answer Selection

Finally after 3 hours of debugging and marking and un-marking all the missing fields in the document, I figured out that I made a small BLUNDER in the actual code. "$BusyPriority" was hardcoded to '2' instead of '1' and that was one of the reason the document was been shown still in Freetime. Other reason was definitely as suggested by @Frantisek Kossuth was that the refresh thing was missing while creation.

Also, during debugging (just for results) I figured out that the Appointment Document created via the script contains only 46 fields compared to 72 fields in the calendar document created via calendar (or saved via calendar), however, the missing fields didn't have any major impact on the document.

Comment: Please, provide more info. I can't tell your problem is server task, database view, or document content...

Comment: Have just updated the code with some more detailed description. Any feedback would be really appreciated..Thanks..!

Comment: and "manually refreshed from NOTES" means... document resaved, refreshed view?

Comment: Manually refresh from NOTES means opening the calendar and hitting an F5 button (refreshing the view of calendar entries I believe)

Comment: There is a new calendar API. Have you tried that one?

Comment: Not yet, will have to look into it. But I don't feel that it would have anything to do with this? From the answers I understand that I would still have the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, what you need is view refresh. The snippet uses "($ApptUNID)" view, so after creating the entry use code like this (you need to provide correct params for mail file path/server):

```
  try {
        var v:NotesView = db.getView('($ApptUNID)');
        if (v) {
              v.refresh();
        }
  } catch(e) {
      //add error handler
  }
```

Trivia: Ulrich's snippet contains `view.refresh()` call when deleting entry, but does not for creating one...

Comment: You are absolutely right. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a ton..! However, I made one more mistake even after refresh it would still show up in free time. Now, this leads me to the other answer on the same question, there are certain server side fields which are missing because of which it still appears under free time. I will just make a comparison suggested by that answer and update script and the current answer accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: The template will leave some cruft items on the entries when it saves them.  Plus there are some items that get added by the template but are only used for certain kinds of entries (e.g. All Day Events or Anniversaries).   You only need a handful of items to get a entry on the Calendar and into busytime.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this type of development has some difficult because the calendar entries have a few internal fields that the server uses. I'm pretty sure that the document that you're creating, lacks one or more fields that are needed, and that fields are calculated when you do something like open the document and save it.

I suggest that you dump the full document after have been created, and after you "refreshed" on Lotus Notes. Then, you can compare them using a tool like [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) or [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) and check what fields you are needed.

Just in case, I have this old code in LotusScript to dump a document to a text file. I hope that be useful.

```
Public Sub DumpDocToTextFile(doc As NotesDocument, ByVal s_file As String)
    Dim o_item As NotesItem
    Dim v_value As Variant
    Dim s_value As String
    Dim b_first As Boolean
    Dim i_file As Integer
    Dim v_items As Variant
    Dim a_result() As String
    Dim v_result As Variant

    ReDim a_result(0 To 0) As String

    ForAll it In doc.Items
        Set o_item = it

        s_value = ""
        b_first = True

        v_items = o_item.Values
        v_value = Evaluate({""})

        If IsArray(v_items) Then
            ForAll s In v_items
                If b_first Then
                    v_value = Evaluate("{" + CStr(s) + "}")
                    b_first = False                     
                Else
                    v_value = ArrayAppend(v_value, CStr(s))
                End If
            End ForAll

            s_value = Implode(v_value, s_sep)
        Else
            s_value = CStr(o_item.Values)
        End If

        a_result(UBound(a_result)) = o_item.Name + ";" + Format$(o_item.LastModified, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") + ";" + CStr(o_item.Type) + ";""" + s_value + """"
        ReDim Preserve a_result(0 To UBound(a_result) + 1) As String
    End ForAll

    'v_result = sort(a_result)  '<== Use a sort algorithm here. It will be easier compare between two documents.
    v_result = a_result  '<== Comment this line if you have the sort algorithm

    i_file = FreeFile
    Open s_file For Output As i_file

    ForAll r In v_result
        Print #i_file, r
    End ForAll

    Close i_file        
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, we can't do that since we do not have a handle to document unless we refresh the view..so basically I can just dump it to text file after refresh and not before so there is no comparison possible I guess. Also, the script library provided by Ulrich Krause (there is a link in my question) is kind of very popular and I doubt there could be such a mistake of missing some fields..

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just figured out that certain fields (around 10 -13) are missing, just need to figure out which of those would be requirement for marking document busy (not show up on free time)..Thanks a lot. I will update it accordingly.

Comment: Glad to have helped. It will be great if you can check this answer as accepted :-D  Bye!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your answer lead me towards the solution, however, missing fields actually were not that important. There were 2 errors here, one as pointed out by @Frantisek Kossuth and other was my mistake of setting $BusyPriority wrongly. I have justified the answer selection on top. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing anything with the Notes Calendar then you should keep this bookmark to the officially published schema: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc

That page was created by the C&S dev and support teams to help document as many items as possible (in our spare time).

Also, you do NOT need to manually refresh views like $ApptUNID if you are worried about busytime.  Busytime does **not** use it.  The system is entirely self contained and extracts data from entries when they are updated on the Calendar.

Lastly, you should consider using the C&S API that was officially released in 9.0 and has been updated in each maintenance release with new features or bug fixes.  The API will handle a lot of the ugly details for you like crafting reschedule notices, etc.